# Create Action Method Name That Matches User's Name?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using mvc 5 to create user accounts , and I want the users to have profile paths like so `example.com/username`
is it possible to do it and how if yes ? 
Thanks

Comment: The biggest problem here is that with a route like that, you're going to have a hard time serving anything but user profile views. For example, if you had a controller named `FooController`, attempting to go to `/foo` will catch the user profile route instead, and attempt to find a user named "foo". It would be better to do something like `/u/[username]`. That way there's no ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a routing entry in your global.asax:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route
{
    Url = [username],
    Defaults = new { Controller = "YourController", Action = "YourAction" }
});
```

Then your controller should look like this:

```
class YourControllerController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult YourAction(string username)
    { 
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot and get back to you :)

Comment: Don't actually put that in Global.asax. That's what RouteConfig.cs is for. Global.asax should be left alone unless you have a very good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: not the answer I was looking for , I guess it should be put in RouteConfig instead , and I'm pretty sure there's a cleaner way to do it , thanks anyway mate ,cheers